# kernel mode debugging on visual studio 2012

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, credential-providers

i have a problem with remote debugging in visual studio 2012

My goal is to test credential provider on windows 7 running in vmware player.
I have installed it, added register changes, it works fine.

I have read this tutorials:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj/archive/2011/02/21/1788561.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/wdk/thread/b34c45df-b724-429d-aa11-e315fd987280

i have created pipe in vmware, and tryied to do the same thing as in this video:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj149675.aspx

but in my visual studio there is no Windows Kernel Mode debugger in transport combo box.

(i have only Default and Remote no athentication)

Does anybody know where could I made something wrong?

Thanks in advance, I hope somebody will help :)

P.S.

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, no 3rd parties debugging software

Comment: Did you install the WDK?

Comment: that was the problem. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually with VS2012 there is much better way to debug credential provider, than kernel debugger - you can install MSVS Remote Debugging tools (could be found inside  MSVS 2012 installation ISO) to your VM. 
Attach using "Default Transport" from "Debug->Attach To Process" menu (Qualifier - enter IP address of VM). 
Select LogonUI.exe process inside Available Processes and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

This article was extremely helpful to me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh698272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Follow the instructions very carefully.  Also my VS 2012 did not have a "Driver" menu, UNTIL I installed the latest WDK-8.  After that install my VS 2012 had a Driver menu, and following the instructions in the article linked above got things working for me.  I hope this helps!